# K-means clustering query in PostgreSQL using Embeddings column

Tags: postgresql, k-means, embedding

I have a table named “keywords” with fields: text, embeddings.
The embeddings field is an array type with the embeddings retried from OpenAI embeddings (1536 floats - Ada-002 model).

**Row example**

- Text: “red fox”
- Embeddings: [0.5,0.01,-0.04..]

How can I perform a Postgres query to group rows by N number of clusters?